# Any way in Google sheets queries to concat/append results of two columns and add text to result? (I know there is no concat within sheets queries)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am clear that there is no concat method in google sheets queries but I'm hoping for a workaround. I've seen some suggestions for transpose but can't seem to apply them to my use, hoping for help.

*My actual source sheet has more complexity in columns but I've simplified it to demonstrate*

[image]

Existing Query

```
=query($L$10:$N$27, "SELECT L, M WHERE N = 'Full' LABEL L 'Name', M ''",1)
```

If Concat/Append were available it would look more like

```
=query($L$10:$N$27, "SELECT ("Name is: " & L & " " & M) WHERE N = 'Full' LABEL L 'Name'",1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({"Name is: "&L10:L27&" "&M10:M27, N10:N27}, 
 "select Col1 
  where Col2 = 'Full' 
  label Col1 'Name'", 1))
```

Comment: Elegant and just what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: One follow-up. If I needed this to be a part of a broader query where I wanted the first three columns to return as normal, but the 4th to be a combination of two, would you still use the same as above?

Comment: yes, still same formula. just make sure you got Col references right

Comment: Using the same faux table above, if I wanted to essentially use a query (more of a mysql guy..) like:

SELECT Col1, CONCAT("last name is: " & Col2) WHERE Col3 = 'Full';

Hoping that I'd get a result like
Jane 1 | last name is: Doe 1
Jane 3 | last name is: Doe 3

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I think I may have just figured it out but would love your eyes on it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DpKyQsm88VLT3UugalmSGUsxEuvEMnAtgxGXPLwS170/edit?usp=sharing

Starting at CellF4. Is there a more elegant or correct way to do this?

Also are the elements in the braces {A4:A21,"Last Name is: "&B4:B21, C4:C21, D4:D21} representing the columns in my query separated by the comma?

Comment: yeah, thats pretty much it. you figured it out well

Comment: @player0 - how would this have to be modified if column N contained some nulls?

Comment: @ChrisRosendin can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output?